# how do I see how big a yum repo is?

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I want to sync the repo http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/ locally. How do I know how big it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size varies, as that is actually a link back to 7, and there are hard links within there to other versions.

However, as of 2017-07-25, if you are just looking at that folder alone, it is 7.7GB.

```
[root@pmirror1 centos]# ls
7         build        HEADER.html           RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4   RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Debug-6     TIME
7.0.1406  dir_sizes    HEADER.images         RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-4  RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Debug-7     timestamp.txt
7.1.1503  dostools     project               RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5  RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Security-6
7.2.1511  filelist.gz  RPM-GPG-KEY-beta      RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6  RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Testing-6
7.3.1611  graphics     RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-3  RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7  RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Testing-7
[root@package1 centos]# du -sh 7.3.1611/os/x86_64/
7.7G    7.3.1611/os/x86_64/
[root@package1 centos]#
```

If you are wanting to mirror it, make sure you use rsync, and use the [mirror closest to yourself](https://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/).

If you're planning to use this mirror, you should also mirror updates, which is 16GB.

```
[root@mirror1 centos]# du -sh 7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/
16G     7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/
[root@mirror1 centos]#
```

Comment: oops, for some reason I thought it would redirect me to my closest mirror, but thats mirrorlist. Im actually using cobbler and doing cobbler reposync which does not support mirrorlist

Comment: Correct. In fact, for automation, you're almost always better manually picking the mirror. For example, my autodetcted local mirror has a lower ping time, but less throughput than another one, so I manually picked one after testing a few.